# Spring Application- What is the best way to start a background process?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multiple-processes

I am using Kinesis to consume a stream inside of a Spring Boot App. I'm using the KCL provided by AWS for this and to start it, you define a Kinesis `com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker` instance and call `.run()` on it. I do not wish to use spring-integration for this task.

I want to build an abstraction here so that developers can create several workers and have them run automatically during or after application startup, and then call the respective `.shutdown()` method on Application termination. Right now I'm doing this by creating a `@Component` for each Worker and then `run()` on `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: `@Async` is the idiomatic answer.

Comment: How about `@Scheduled` annotations ? (in addition to `@Async`